# Create new object from another already instantiated object, with the same arguments

Tags: python

Is it possible in python to recreate an object from already instatiated object, with all it's arguments passed into `__init__` method?

Something similar to `inspect.getcallargs`, but for class instances.

For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        self.some_arg = some_arg

def f(a):
    # somehow get all arguments from `a`, with which it was created
    # kwargs = ...?
    # and create a new instance of class with the same (or modified) args:
    return a.__class__(**kwargs)

a = A(100)
new_a = f(a)
print(new_a.some_arg)
>>> 100
```

Comment: See [Main purpose of `__repr__` in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661063/main-purpose-of-repr-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because the arguments of the `__init__` method might have been discarded, used to compute other values, or saved in a multitude of different manners which would be impossible to create a generic method to retrieve.

However, you can achieve flexible object initialization from preset configurable parameters by using [the Factory pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html), and you can copy existing objects using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html). (However, be aware that there are edge cases to deepcopy, so be careful when using it and be sure to read the docs)