# Can you return a __str__ representation of an object within the __repr__ method at recursion level 1?

Tags: python, string, oop, recursion, repr

I am looking for a way to implement a custom `__repr__` function in Python, that handles recursion Pythonically, while maintaining readability.

I have two classes (Foo and Bar) that point to each other in their attributes. Of course, simply putting e.g.:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo({self.bar})'

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, bar_instance):
        if bar_instance is not None:
            bar_instance._foo = self
            
        self._bar = bar_instance

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        self.foo = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Bar({self.foo})'

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo_instance):
        if foo_instance is not None: 
            foo_instance._bar = self
            
        self._foo = foo_instance

bar = Bar()
foo = Foo(bar)
```

Would result in a recursion error. Luckily, there's the `@recursive_repr()` from [reprlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html) to the rescue. See my implementation below.

```
from reprlib import recursive_repr


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

    @recursive_repr()
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Foo({self.bar})'

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, bar_instance):
        if bar_instance is not None:
            bar_instance._foo = self
            
        self._bar = bar_instance

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foo=None):
        self.foo = None

    @recursive_repr()
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Bar({self.foo})'

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo_instance):
        if foo_instance is not None: 
            foo_instance._bar = self
            
        self._foo = foo_instance

bar = Bar()
foo = Foo(bar)
```

However, the custom implementation with `fillvalue='...'` doesn't improve readability much, in my opinion. Also, this representation of e.g. the `foo` instance - although I know this [isn't required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661063/what-is-the-relationship-between-repr-and-eval-and-what-is-the-main-purpo) - doesn't make it very reproducible, necessarily.

```
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> foo = Foo(bar)
>>> foo
... Foo(Bar(...))
```

I am looking for an implementation where I can print a string representation of the `foo` instance, instead of printing the triple dots. I would want an output that'd be something like this: `Foo(Bar(my_foo_object))` in which I'd be able to define `my_foo_object` as the return value of the `Foo` `__str__` method.

Although in the above example this might not make a ton of sense, in my non-MWE it would provide a more intuitive perspective on the objects and their values.

In brief: is it possible to return a `__str__` representation of an object within an objects `recursive_repr` *at recursion level 1*?

Comment: You could use the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/reprlib.py) of `recursive_repr` as base for your own implementation. Mainly the `return fillvalue` must be changed.

Comment: @Sam Your first code will not be recursive. Where does the `self.bar` attribute come from?

Comment: @GIZ: Oh, I see what you mean. There is no recursion, but I think you mean: `self.foo`. That is only set to `None` in the above code.

Comment: @quamrana The first code OP posted doesn't result in a recursion error. `f'Foo({self.bar})'` will rather raise `ArributeError` exception.

Comment: @GIZ Apologies, apparently this wasn't clear. The triple dots were supposed to represent truncated classes. I will edit the code so it represents less ambiguously what I meant.

Comment: @MichaelButscher overwriting the package in a way that `fillvalue` returns something different was also my first thought. However, I'd like to avoid writing my own package, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Foo.__str__()` method? It seems to break the recursion because `f'{self.foo}` calls `Foo.__str__()` and doesn't perpetuate the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for an implementation where I can print a string
> representation of the `foo` instance, instead of printing the triple
> dots. I would want an output that'd be something like this:
> `Foo(Bar(my_foo_object))` in which I'd be able to define `my_foo_object`
> as the return value of the Foo `__str__` method.

You need to define custom `__str__` for both classes:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "CustomBar"
```

and in `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'Foo({self.bar})'
```

fstrings in Python default to `__str__` you don't need to call `str(self.bar)`. In this case, you don't need to decorate your `__repr__` functions with `@reprlib.recursive_repr` as no recursion is taking place essentially when custom `__str__` functions are *present*.

Please note that you can override the `Repr.fillvalue` string which defaults to the ellipsis `...` or `reprlib.recursive_repr(fillvalue='somethingCustomHere')`.

> In brief: is it possible to return a `__str__` representation of an
> object within an objects `recursive_repr` at recursion level 1?

Definig `__str__` would return the string representation, the string returned by `__str__`, without necessitating the need of recursive call to `__repr__` and thus eliminating the use of `recursive_repr` to handle recursion.

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed looks like an elegant solution!